# Maven - How to exclude dependencies from generated JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I have 3 projects that looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that the common DB code has a converter class, and I am getting the below error while running the Business logic.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class com.td.sba.iep.jpa.converters.ModeltoDBAttributeConverter] registered multiple times
```

What I did:
I tried to exclude the dependencies while packaging the Utility classes using the below code in pom.xml.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Fools the plugin into creating the code only jar instead of the runnable one -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when I include the exec jar created into the Business logic, it shows that the utility classes are not found.

**WHAT I NEED:**
How do I fix the 'org.hibernate.AssertionFailure'?
Should I exclude the dependencies while creating the jar from utility classes? How do I do it?

Incase it matters, I am using Eclipse.

attaching pom.xml: BusinessLogic

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Use maven profiles to control Spring Boot profile. -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>local</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activeProfile>dev</activeProfile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
    <artifactId>BusinessLogicClass</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Business Logic</name>
    <description>Business Logic to handle user requests</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
            <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonDBLogic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
            <artifactId>UtilityClasses</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
    </distributionManagement>


</project>
```

**Utility Class:**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties> 
 <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
 <artifactId>UtilityClasses</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>UtilityClasses</name>
 <description>Utility Classes used by Business Logic class</description>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
     <artifactId>datecalc-common</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
     <artifactId>datecalc-jdk8</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
            <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonDBLogic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>  
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Fools the plugin into creating the code only jar instead of the runnable one -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>      
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Common DB Logic:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.usermanagement</groupId>
    <artifactId>CommonDBLogic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CommonDBLogic</name>
    <description>Common DB Logic used by Business class</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Fools the plugin into creating the code only jar instead of the runnable one -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you actually building a SpringBoot JAR here?  Or where you just using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as a "hack" to try to build the JAR differently (but originally just using maven-jar-plugin)?   In any case, it might help to show more of your pom.xml(s).

Comment: I have added the pom.xml for all three projects.

Comment: Since you already have CommonDB dependencies on your UtilityProject pom, remove this CommonDB dependency from your business logic pom. This error is because you have 2 classes (same class) being registered with same name. If you already have CommonDB dependency on UtilityProject and you use this UtilityProject as dependency on Business, you don't need to import it twice.

Comment: Thanks DaviM. Removing the CommonDB dependency worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use `<exclusions>` element on this project dependencies? Like:

Business Logic Project `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.utility.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>UtilityProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>group.id.jar.you.want.to.exclude</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact.id.jar.you.want.to.exclude</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you already have CommonDB dependencies on your UtilityProject pom, remove this CommonDB dependency from your business logic pom. This error is because you have 2 classes (same class) being registered with same name. If you already have CommonDB dependency on UtilityProject and you use this UtilityProject as dependency on Business, you don't need to import it twice.

Comment: I tried using exclusion. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks DaviM. Removing the CommonDB dependency worked.